# Is it possible to merge users as just one entry in a Calender group

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

Let's say I have a calender group with like 10 people. What if I would like to have instead of those 10 users/names only one entry that shows me all the dates of those 10 people. It might be an odd question, but I got it from a user and I just wanted to check if that was possible.
Thank you for the help.

Edit: It's not about the right side view, the display of the calenders itself, but the names listest. So, instead of user1, user2, user3,... The user wanted just to have one entry like "users" and when selecting it, only one calender with all user dates is shown.

Comment: Have you tried overlay mode? Or you could create a shared calendar for those 10 users to access.

Comment: @spikey_richie thanks I checked what you mean, but it's more about the shown users in the group. I edited my question to make it more clear. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Yeah so I think you want to create a shared calendar, which is a different type of calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's *impossible*, as I know, one user in the name list corresponds a calendar in the right, we could only select multiple calendar at once and view in overlay mode to check them in a view as spikey_richie mentioned.